# Making queries in HSQLDB during transaction

Tags: sql, database, hsqldb

I'm running a test using HSQLDB and I want to be able making select queries on database while this test to see what is changing. I suppose transaction or something else is blocking the database while test and I'm not able to make queries ...
Is it possible to configure hsql server in that way to be able to do these queries?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is valid if you are starting a HyperSQL Server and connecting with the `jdbc:hsqldb:hsql:xxxx` connection URL.

The default transaction isolation model is LOCKS. In this model, the tables are locked when their rows are modified during a transaction. You need to use the MVCC model for the database to allow other connections to access the table.

However, when you modify the rows, these changes are only visible to the transaction that makes the change until it commits the data and the changes become visible to other connections.